# IPv6 Neighbor Discovery procedure with a ping example

Tags: switch, ipv6, icmpv6, network-discovery

Given the following capture (click to zoom):

[image: log]

There are 3 routers attached to a switch. One of them pings FF02::1 (packet #2). I understand, that the other two routers have to figure out the first one's link-layer address (hence the NS and NA messages #3,4,5,6). After that both of them sends their ping reply.

My question is, why are those additional NDP messages exchanged (#11-14)? They are coming from the router, which sent the echo request. It should already know about the link-layer addresses of the other two from the Neighbor Solicitation messages. What am I missing?

Comment: These come 5 seconds after the echo packets. Is this behaviour consistent if you repeat the experiment? You could clear the neighbor cache before repeating it.

Comment: Yes, it happens every time. I wonder if it has anything to do with Neighbor Unreachability Protocol, as the DELAY_FIRST_PROBE_TIME (RFC4861 page 70) is set to 5 sec.

Comment: You could try to disable NUD or change the timer to test your theory (if possible on your system).